Framework 16 laptop: headphones - trackpad - problems / Secure Boot? / Ubuntu 24.04
Framework 16 laptop:
Framework 16 laptop
I bought Windows 11. Windows won't boot
Windows 11 Installation on the Framework Laptop 16 DIY Edition
[Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS booted. Headphones won't work. No headphones option in the sound menu.
Trackpad scrolls and clicks, but stopped doing all of the other stuff that it was doing.
This is all brand new a few days old.
The Framework 16 laptop was supposed to be compatible with Fedora. I tried to install Fedora, but the computer won't let me. I was hoping maybe Fedora would let me use my headphones
Secure Boot. I don't know what it is, but I know it won't let me disable it
I got a Windows USB to boot, but says there are no drivers detected
I can't or don't know how to install the drivers.
Framework laptop 16 BIOS and driver releases:
Framework Laptop 16 BIOS and Driver Releases
AMD software: Adrenalin Edition Application:
AMD Software: Adrenalin Edition™ Application
I have been always using a Mac, and I'm pretty sure that I don't know how to use Ubuntu.

Welcome to AskUbuntu. AskUbuntu works best if you ask a single, clear, answerable question. It is unclear exactly what you are asking, and the formatting makes your question difficult to follow. It looks like you want some kind of interactive discussion to help you diagnose a hardware fault. AskUbuntu isn't the best format for that kind of help, as it may not be answerable without a LOT more information from you...but folks here will try.
